# Show current user posts in custom post type query

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions

I have a custom post type named `'saved-orders'`, and I want to edit the main query so the current user logged in only sees their posts.

I've added this to my `functions.php` but it's still displaying the posts from all users:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_query_vars' );

function custom_query_vars( $query ) {


  global $current_user;  

  if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
    if ( get_post_type() == 'saved-orders' ) {
      $query->set( 'author' => $current_user->ID );
    }

  }
  return $query;
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What you added should have generated a fatal error as it's not valid syntax, `$query->set( 'author' => $current_user->ID );`, `=>` isn't used inside function calls like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 fundamental problems here:

### Problem 1

`pre_get_posts` lets you modify a query before it happens, and in this case you're modifying the main query before it happens.

But you do this:

```
if ( get_post_type() == 'saved-orders' ) {
```

`get_post_type` shouldn't work here as it's too early, the main query hasn't happened yet. Instead, lets ask the query object:

```
if ( 'saved-orders' === query->get( 'post_type' ) {
```

### Problem 2

This is a syntax error, and not valid PHP:

```
$query->set( 'author' => $current_user->ID );
```

`=>` is only used in 2 situations:

```
array(
    'key' => 'value'
)
```

and

```
for ( $array as $key => $value )
```

Neither of which are function calls. The correct way to call the `set` method is:

```
$query->set( 'queryvar', $new_value );
```

With some beginner level PHP knowledge you should now be able to fix your filter.